# Strange IE 7 behavior in an absolute table header with fixed widths

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, scroll, fixed-header-tables

Once again, I'm at a loss with IE7 on this one.

I'm making a fixed header scrollable body table based almost entirely on CSS (horizontal scroll still needs javascript to work). It is a modified version based off of [this one](http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/12/css-scrolling-tables-with-fixed.html). It looks good in the browsers I've checked: Chrome, Firefox and IE8+. However, in IE7 (and probably lower) the header misbehaves, like the naughty black sheep it is, and I can't figure out why.

Any fixes / improvements / suggestions / alterations are appreciated and encouraged. :)
(I was going for a windows-esque look)

Here's a [live jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6T3h4/)

Here's a comparison pic between Firefox and IE7
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest an alternative look for IE7 :)

First of all - I see that you've got the word *operation* in the third column hidden everywhere except IE - that's where the problem starts. IE doesn't apply the `height: inherit` declaration on the `div`. Setting it to 22px did the trick - at least it doesn't break the layout. See here - http://fiddle.jshell.net/6T3h4/6/

But the problem remains with the border... my advise is to delete the border only for ie7 using the `*border: 0;` which will be ignored by everyone else.

As a result - at least you will have a much better visual presentation compared to your current one))) see here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6T3h4/7/ (*in this example I simply deleted the border to save time - so it disappears everywhere in **all** browsers. Use `*border: 0;` instead, if you want to*)

It is **partially** a solution, I would recommend to use it only if you don't manage to find out why IE misplaces the elements in `thead`. So to say, as a last resort, but not as a way to do all the time ;) If I have some more time, I'll see into this problem, but I'm not sure I need to)

Comment: Good answer. I had also considered just hiding the border with the starhack, but was hoping for better. I just wish IE could play nice at least once when I do these projects. I'll accept your answer because you solved the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

just add this code:

```
table.list thead tr {*position: relative;} /* For IE 7 */
```

Finding a way to work on the `tfoot` but not working.

Comment: It doesn't do anything at all on my end. Could you provide an example? You can use [mine as a base](http://jsfiddle.net/6T3h4/).

Comment: No, it's still misbehaving :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6T3h4/5/ This one? I am trying to check, but not sure becoz I have IE 9 and I use IE 7 mode to check. Not sure if I can trust it!

Comment: Still no. Can't you debug on your end? All these comments... :P

Comment: Er... I want you to debug, coz I said na, I have IE 9. Can't trust if its emulator is pure IE 7, as it is working! :P

Comment: Are you debugging by setting both the web and document mode to IE7? Because that's what I'm doing :P

Comment: One thing about IE is true. It rules the corporate world, which use Windows as the main OS. Lets pray that IE dies. Else, you can give a note saying that `Sorry! Please upgrade at least to IE 8 for a supported basic UX!`